# Does YouTube support proper output of DTS encoded files?

Tags: surround-sound

Also, if not, does HTML5 or Flash support this?

DTS is an encoding technology to allow 5.1 sound to go over one SPDIF or Optical cable, as opposed to 6 separate analog cables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer, from what I can gather, is no.

While you can get 5.1 sound from videos on YouTube, you are **not actually sourcing 5.1 DTS data, or Dolby Digtal for the matter**.

While Air3 supports [DTS](http://www.engadget.com/2011/10/03/flash-11-and-air-3-landing-tonight-and-delivering-7-1-surround-s/), Flash11 [does not](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/AudioDecoder.html):

> Multichannel audio is supported only on AIR for TV devices. On all
>   other devices, hasMultiChannelAudio() always returns false.

The [current solution](http://www.overdigital.com/2012/10/02/flash-player-and-5-1-surround-sound/) that gives 5.1 output but doesn't actually source 5.1 input is up-conversion (Dolby Pro Logic II):

> Flash Player on the desktop supports 2 channel audio. Does this mean
>   you can offer users only stereo content? No, there is a popular option
>   to support surround sound. ...Flash Player fully support formats that
>   rely on source files with 2 channel audio, and then transform them to
>   5.1 (or up to 9.1) surround sound, such as Dolby Pro Logic II

HTML5 supports multichannel audio that includes 5.1, see the [Web Audio API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#ChannelLayouts). I can't find anything indicating that HTML5 supports DTS (pass through or not). I also currently have no way to test it myself. If anyone else can shine some light on this matter I would be interested.

If you are having trouble getting 5.1 in browsers, the following references may be helpful:

The media format and the browser [must be compatible (circa 2012)](http://www.brucewiggins.co.uk/?p=265). The experience of [these forum users](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/%23!topic/chrome/PZwm-qB7TIQ) is a good example:

> - WHAT WORKS IN 5.1 SURROUND
>
> Games
>   Youtube.com in Firefox ONLY
>   ANY website with audio other than Youtube (All browsers)
>   Youtube embedded videos (on Facebook or anywhere else other than youtube.com proper)
>
> - WHAT ONLY WORKS IN STEREO
>
> Youtube.com in Chrome or Internet Explorer
>   All media players (iTunes,
>   VLC, Windows Media Player, Winamp)
>   Clicking on a Youtube link from anywhere on the web switches Youtube from 5.1 to stereo on the new tab (if I go back to the embedded tab, it is still 5.1).

It may be worthy to note that your speaker setup apparently matters according the those same users:

> I got everything fixed now.
>
> First, I was VERY surprised when I tried your program, AIMP3 and it
>   DID work in surround sound ! Only media player that was actually
>   working.
>
> But then, I plugged my new Z906 speakers and everything works in 5.1
>   now, everywhere. Chrome, IE, Games, Music, everything.
>
> So, it was my old speakers.
>
> Thank you again for your help !

If you are [having trouble with Chrome](http://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/2dwgmo/chromeyoutubehtml5no_51_sound/) you may try starting it with these command line parameters:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-audio-output-resampler --try-supported-channel-layouts
```

Comment: To the anonymous user who recently down-voted this answer, please provide feedback about how it can be improved.

Comment: I have a Macbook and LG BH9540TW surround sound system. I am able to get 5.1 surround sound on some downloaded videos, which suggests that the speakers are properly configured and Macbook can provide 5.1 output to the LG system. But I tried youtube on Firefox, Chrome and Safari but there is no surround sound on the test videos. Could you please suggest how can I get 5.1 surround sound for Youtube?

Comment: Remember to actually close Chrome to test the command line parameters: https://superuser.com/q/269385/624847

Comment: While I can't find it anywhere, YouTube supports the HTML5 player now, and it's possible this has changed. From what I've seen though, YouTube takes surround audio and downmixes it to 2-channel.