# Does YouTube support output of 7.1 surround?

Tags: audio, youtube, surround-sound

I recently got a new motherboard that supports surround sound 7.1 with optical outputs. I have read [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/906385/does-youtube-support-proper-output-of-dts-encoded-files) that explains at length the details of using 5.1 but there is no mention of 7.1 surround (also the answer is from 2016 and things may have improved since then).

While I'm sure I can get things working with a DTS encoded file to work from VLC, I'd like to know if I can get this support on YouTube as I do watch a lot of videos on there. There is a [7.1 test video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TdLTe_yckY), but I'd like to know if it works before doing all the hardware setup.

I am using Chrome **Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)** on WIndows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not for this site, but webapps, the answer is no. Youtube does not support surround at all. Everything is outputted at stereo. I have a 5.1 surround system, but all videos on youtube sound stereo. Even the comments will tell you that they are stereo sounds, not surround.

If you only want to do this with youtube, don't waste your time. But for movies, definitely do.

Comment: thanks for weighing in. Wondering why do people make those surround videos then?

Comment: Either it may have worked, or they wrongly assumed it worked but never actually tested. I mean, on my 5.1 surround set, these videos sound very stereoish, but they are still stereo. Can easily be mistaken for surround.

Comment: There is one other thing I can think of... they may be dolby surround demo's. This means they are stereo signals and a dolby decoder will try to turn it into surround. It is not true surround though, but it can make movies sound more wide as much as it can also screw up with movies.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021, YouTube does support 5.1 surround sound both for videos and for live streaming. This may however only work with specific hardware and not in a web browser. See the respective help articles on their site:

[Watch YouTube on TV with 5.1 surround sound](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/11904456)

[Stream 5.1 surround sound audio on YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/13440750)

(The latter mentions some supported encoders.)

I have tested this using a Chromecast with Google TV on a Samsung Q9FN TV with an Onkyo 7.1 decoder (only 5.1 speakers attached).
The MP4 file uploaded had 2 audio streams, the first one stereo and the second one 5.1 with channel assignment L R C Lfe Lrs Rrs (both audio streams encoded in AAC).

(One restriction I noticed is that when casting the video to the Chromecast from my phone, the 5.1 Surround option did not appear and the video was played back in stereo. Only directly selecting it on the Chromecast made it play correctly with 5.1 audio.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).