# Separate google Chrome process using CPU

Tags: google-chrome

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this but...in the Task Manager, there's always a separate Chrome process that's running by itself. **when i start my computer, it starts automatically.** no browser whatsoever.

If I open the browser, the browser shows as a different **group** of processes from that one process. If I right click on that process and go to file location, it takes me to the Chrome application file in program files.

I have four extensions: ABP, Google Dictionary, IDM, and Session Buddy. These were there before this mysterious process turned up. I can right click and end the process, and it stops till the next restart. I ran a full scan on Windows Defender Security Center, and it was clean.

What is this mysterious version of Chrome? How do i fix it? Should i reinstall Chrome? I didn't do it yet as it's a bit of a nuisance.

Thank you so much :]

when i start my computer. no Chrome icon in notification area (haven't opened Chrome yet):
[Separate Chrome Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiaFD.png)

after opening Chrome: [Google Chrome processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnQ3n.png)

Chrome background process settings: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRGVg.png)

"Open File Location" (it's the same as Google Chrome browser path + the same file): [File Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWuuD.png)

**it only seems to come up when i'm connected to the internet (win startup).** but doesn't seem to use internet - checked on resource monitor. just using the cpu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Google Chrome leave running processes behind even after closing the browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/269385/why-does-google-chrome-leave-running-processes-behind-even-after-closing-the-bro)

Comment: @Ramhound hey! it's actually not the same problem i'm having.

Comment: If that is the case you should do the following and update your question.  Backup your current Chrome user profile, nuke the current user profile and reboot your system, then launch Chrome and verify if the behavior still happens.  After you have done that update question with relevant information

Comment: @MoonRunestar the file path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application with Chrome application file highlighted. i added some images to my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It's Chrome's background process and it's probably been there for a long time, you just didn't notice it. You can find its icon in the notification area, next to system clock. It may be hidden - in that case, click the arrow to reveal it.

This process is used by some extensions (or, strictly speaking, Chrome apps) to run their background tasks. It also makes Chrome start faster.

If you don't want it, right-click the notification area icon and uncheck appropriate option.

Related question: [Why does Google Chrome leave running processes behind even after closing the browser?](https://superuser.com/q/269385/194694)

Comment: hey, thank for responding. there's no icon in the notification area. i have disabled "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" option. and as i said, it starts automatically when i start my computer. i always have Task Manager open, so i'm 100% sure it wasn't there before. i can end it in the Task Manager and work fine on Chrome browser.

Comment: i added an image to my question showing the notification area and that process in Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run (win+R), type msconfig.

In msconfig box, go to startup tab and see if any unnecessary service is present related to chrome.

Uncheck the unnecessary service and apply, then reboot and see if it comes again.